# Conditionally sum and round to nearest even value row by row using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to round the sum of a row of values to the nearest even number, except if the value is between 0.75 and 3, then the value should round to 2.

**Data**

```
Location    range   type    Q1 24   Q2 24   Q3 24   Q4 24   
NY          low     SS      0       0.79    0       0   
NY          low     SS      0       0       0       0   
CA          low     AA      0.24    0.34    0.93    1.07    
CA          low     AA      1.71    0.57    0       0   
CA          low     BB      0.08    0.11    0.65    0.47    
CA          low     BB      0       0       2       0   
CA          low     DD      0.35    0.5     1.37    1.57
```

**Desired**

```
  Location     range    type    Q1 24   Q2 24   Q3 24   Q4 24    rounded_sum
    NY          low     SS      0       0.79    0       0        2
    NY          low     SS      0       0       0       0        0
    CA          low     AA      0.24    0.34    0.93    1.07     2 
    CA          low     AA      1.71    0.57    0       0        2
    CA          low     BB      0.08    0.11    0.65    0.47     2  
    CA          low     BB      0       0       2       0        2
    CA          low     DD      0.35    0.5     1.37    1.57     4
```

**Doing**

SO member helped, but needing to tweak if the sum is
greater or equal to 0.75 it should round to the value 2.

```
# using np.where, check if integer part is even or odd
# if odd, add 1 else, keep the integer as is
df2['rounded_sum']=np.where(df2['rounded_sum'].astype(int)%2==1,
                           df2['rounded_sum'].astype(int) +1, 
                           df2['rounded_sum'].astype(int))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: What's the upper bound for rounding to 2? (I'm asking because the sum of the last row is greater than 0.75, but clearly the "round to the value 2" rule doesn't apply there. At what point does that rule cease to apply?)

Comment: @MarkDickinson sure I just updated- If the value is between 0.75 and 3, the value should be rounded to 2. Other than that, round the sum of the values to the nearest even value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `round` within `np.where`:

```
df["sum"] = df[["Q1 24", "Q2 24", "Q3 24", "Q4 24"]].sum(axis=1)
df["rounded_sum"] = np.where(df["sum"].between(0.75,3),2,round(df["sum"].div(2))*2)

>>>
  Location range type  Q1 24  Q2 24  Q3 24  Q4 24   sum  rounded_sum
0       NY   low   SS   0.00   0.79   0.00   0.00  0.79          2.0
1       NY   low   SS   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00  0.00          0.0
2       CA   low   AA   0.24   0.34   0.93   1.07  2.58          2.0
3       CA   low   AA   1.71   0.57   0.00   0.00  2.28          2.0
4       CA   low   BB   0.08   0.11   0.65   0.47  1.31          2.0
5       CA   low   BB   0.00   0.00   2.00   0.00  2.00          2.0
6       CA   low   DD   0.35   0.50   1.37   1.57  3.79          4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you can define a function that will round your number

```
def func(n):
    if 0.75 <= n <= 3:
        return 2
    elif n % 2 < 1:
        return n - n % 2
    else:
        return n - n % 2 + 2
```

and then form a new array and fill it with the sums of Q1 Q2 Q3 and Q4:

```
sums = df.iloc[:, 3:].sum(axis=1)
```

Then you can modify your array with "map" and our function and write it to your dataframe:

```
df["rounded"] = list(map(func, sums))
```

or replace it with lambda:

```
df["rounded"] = list(map(lambda n: 2 if 0.75 <= n <= 3 else n - n % 2 if n % 2 < 1 else n - n % 2 + 2, sums))
```

But I think that code without lambda looks better)

P.S. sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `np.where`:

```
s = df.filter(like='Q').sum(axis=1)
df['rounded_sum'] = np.where(s.between(0.75,2), 2, (s/2).round()*2)
```

**note** `.between(0.75, 2)` and `.between(0.75,3)` would give the same outcome due to the `round()` op.

Comment: sure let me test thank you @Quang

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
# sum the rows from column "type" onwards
df['sum'] = df.iloc[:, 3:].sum(axis=1)

# round the sum according to the requirements
df['rounded_sum'] = np.where((df['sum'] >= 0.75) & (df['sum'] <= 2.99), 2, np.round(df['sum'] / 2) * 2)
```